# Does git keep old files for a while if you rewrite history?

Tags: git

I accidentally committed sensitive information to a repository and then did a force push to remove that commit from the public repository.

After that I changed all exposed passwords.

This is a technical question about git. Will that record of the deleted commit remain existing inside my local git repository? And will it disappear after a period of time? Where is this documented?

Comment: Yes. It's still in the local repo and remote repo for a while (quite long in fact). Check `git gc`. Better to change all passwords that were exposed.

Answer (score 1):

After a `push --force`, the old historys' commits are still part of the repository. They are just not reachable via any branch. (There is a discussion about dangling commits resulting from a `push --force` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564658/git-are-these-dangling-commits)). When there is no reference to a commit anymore, a commit becomes dangling and will be garbage collected by `git gc`(see  [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) for git gc documentation).

However, as long as there are any references to a commit, it will not be garbage collected. This is the case if there is no branch and no tag pointing to the commit and its not referenced from the `reflog` any more. The reflog part is explained in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765586/7598462).

So, the answer is yes, your old commits will continue to exist, and yes, they will disappear after a period of time, but it's hard to tell when. You can try to remove all references by hand (via branch/tag deletion, if relevant, and `git reflog --expire=<time>` for the reflog reference, see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)).

For a deeper understanding of whats going on deep down, I can recommend [this](http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/plumbing) article.